# how to return values from python to html and vice versa

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js

Ok so i am using d3.js to generate a collapsible tree. The json format I am getting is being converted by a python script which calculates stuff based on database values and etc.

Now the python script starts off with the argument which would be the root to the tree, based on that root, i do my calculations and get the dependency dictionary and convert into json format which is read by the html file.

Now I want to know how to
1)add a drop down to that html page which will hold values. Now these values will be calculated by my `<python script A>`. SO my script will query the db and get some values, and i would want those values as a drop down in the html page. Selecting any one of the value, it should return that value to my another `<python script B>` which would then use that value as the root and generate the json values.

2)Once the json value is generated, i would like to have a button that would refresh just the graph, not sure if that is possible. Like, select a value from dropdown and click on a button "Show Graph", which would then run my `<python script B>` and generate the json file and show the first node of the tree.

havent used html, so i don't know how to get this integrated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. to add drop-down first get the list of all those values which you need to show in drop-down box.
   render html page using this list like:

   dropdownvalues = [val1, val2, val3, val4, ...]

   return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                             {'dropdownvalues':dropdownvalues },
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))

now actual rendering code is:

```
{%if dropdownvalues %}
  <select name='DDL1' id='DDL1'>
    {% for val in dropdownvalues  %}
      <option>{{val}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
   </select>
{% endif %}
```

1. now add button submit

   now add jquery script to perform action on submit button

   $('#bttSubmit').click(function() {

   ```
           $.ajax({
               url: 'action_url',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {'val': $('#DDL1').val()},
               success: function (result) {
                 // json response in result
                 // perform necessary operations
                 // take the data and apply it on particular chart.
               }
           });  

   });
   ```

in the django view you can process the input data and return json response back to browser
and you can process json data the way you want